# How to keep my numbers from rounding?

Tags: python

I have some code that takes values from a dictionary and attempts to figure out the per unit price of an item. However, I cannot figure out how to keep the values from rounding.

If I do this:

```
total_price = int(item['Item Price'][1:]) #First character is a dollar sign
qty = int(item['Quantity'])
unit_price = total_price/qty
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '88.75'
```

So, I tried `float`ing the value:

```
total_price = int(float(item['Item Price'][1:]))
qty = int(item['Quantity'])
unit_price = total_price/qty
```

Which doesn't return an error, but it then rounds up and I only get whole numbers.

How can I get the actual per piece price and not a rounded value? Thanks

Comment: The Decimal class might be of some help

Comment: If you don't want whole numbers, then why are you using an `int`?

Comment: don't ever use float for money

Comment: Can you show some examples number you want to get along with the strings quantity and price.

Comment: Besides echoing @Oli's comment, I'm surprised that anything you've tried rounds *up*.

Comment: Don't worry about deleting the question, if it needs to be gone the community will get around to deleting it eventually. It's sometimes useful to have different search terms that lead to the same answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, I assumed as much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `qty` and `total_price` to be a float:

```
total_price = float(item['Item Price'][1:])
qty = float(item['Quantity'])
```

This will cause the division to be between two floating point values.

Using `int` explicitly says you want integers, which gives you whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring during division

```
>>> print 3/2
1
>>> print 3.0/2
1.5
>>>
```